# Cefsharp Play videos in Picture-in-picture mode

Tags: cefsharp

I am not able to play the video in pip mode. I am using Cefsharp version 71. Do I need to enable any flag for supporting pip mode in Cefsharp? Video is not getting displayed in pip mode but audio is getting played.

However, in normal mode video is working fine.

Comment: Support was added in https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2776/add-picture-in-picture-support you are using a very old version that doesn't support `PIP`. Version `83.4.20` is the current supported version and should support `PIP`.

Comment: @amaitland thanks for the update. I'll update to the latest version.